# Specifying runtime behavior of a program

Tags: garbage-collection, specifications, latency

Are there any languages/extensions that allow the programmer to define general runtime behavior of a program during specific code segments?

Some garbage-collected languages let you modify the behavior of the GC at runtime. Like in lua, the collectgarbage function lets you do this. So, for example, you can stop the GC when you want to be sure that CPU resources aren't used in garbage collection for a critical section of code (after which you start the GC again).

I'm looking for a general way to specify intended behavior of the program without resorting to specifying specific GC tweaks. I'm interested even in an on-paper sort of specification method (ie something a programmer would code toward, but not program syntax that would actually implement that behavior). The point would be that this could be used to specify critical sections of code that shouldn't be interrupted (latency dependent activity) or other intended attributes of certain codepaths (maximum time between an output and an input or two outputs, average running time, etc).

For example, this syntax might describe that maximum time latencyDependentStuff should take is 5 milliseconds:

```
requireMaxTime(5) {
   latencyDependentStuff();
}
```

Has anyone seen anything like this anywhere before?